# HMM - Forward Algorithm - Initial State Distribution

Tags: hidden-markov-model

In my case, I have a dataset of observations which have not been produced by an HMM meaning that I do not know what kind and how many hidden states should exist there.
So, the only known factor are the observations. 
After the training of my model using a specific number of hidden states each time, I needed then to apply forward algorithm to evaluate the model. My problem is that since I do not know what kind of hidden states there are, I am not able to assign proper initial pi values, therefore I decided to assign same probabilities for all states equal to 1/N.
Do you find my approach meaningful?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Within the context of each training session, you do indeed know the specific number of hidden states, as you are using that as an input to the training.  Also note that just because the  process hasn't been produced by an HMM doesn't mean that it's meaningless to think of what states might, conceptually, be an adequate basis for an HMM model, and use that to help come up with initial probabilities.  Furthermore, you can estimate the initial probabilities as part of the estimation process.

Comment: You are right... IN my mind I do think of some probabilities when I have for example number of states 3 .. but the thing is that I have to confirm that the right  number of states is 3. To do that I have to train my data a number of times experimenting with different values of n, where 2<n<10 > In this case how can I think of the initial probabilities when I do not know what kind of states the 4 states, 5 states, 6 states etc are?